# How can I make a Drupal responsive theme fixed

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-themes

I am using the Mayo theme and love it except that I do not want it to be responsive on the desktop. (I am using it for mobile devices.)

Does anyone have guidelines on how to remove the responsiveness?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Many things ... I specified fixed body and column widths in the settings and also tried overriding them in a custom css file. No change. I also tried using the previous version (7.x-1.3) but it didn't help. I'm using 7.x-2.0 now.

Comment: I should have added that changing the settings helps for a while but if I make the window too narrow it moves the left sidebar under the content which I do not want to happen.

Comment: Have you tried using media queries in your css?

Comment: I'm using a single sub-theme for the desktop. However it does have some media queries in the css. Do you think I could remove them from the sub-theme and not affect the other sub-themes? I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: I removed the media queries from the sub theme style sheet and it did not make any changes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Mayo theme for device only, you should use [Mobile Theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/mobile_theme) module to specify the Mayo to use only for the mobile devices. For the desktop then you can use other available Drupal themes.

Comment: I want to use Mayo for all devices. I have created a sub-theme for desktop use. I do not want to use another theme.